# Euler's Bernoulli number Identity help

Tags: number-theory, power-series

My professor and I derived the $n$th Bernoulli number as the recursion
$$B_n=\frac{-1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1}{k}B_k.$$
Later, in a paper I was reading, there is a similar identity attributed to Euler, where
$$-(n+1)B_n=\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}\binom{n}{k}B_kB_{n-k}$$

Certainly reindexing the first equation would help to get 
$$-(n-1)B_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n}{k}B_k$$

But now the problem lies with the multiplication of each summand by the $(n-k)$th Bernoulli number and this, along with the index starting at 2 gives the identity.  I'm failing to see the math in this.  The paper I'm reading states that $b(x)=\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_nx^n}{n!}$ yields the result, but I'm not seeing how.  Is there an online proof I can read to help clarify?

EDIT:  The paper I'm reading actually states that the Euler Identity is a consequence of 
$$b(x)^2=(1-x)b(x)-xb'(x)$$
This is really where I'm seeing confusion.  I've proved the first identity independently using the ideas provided in the answer below, but not being familiar with Laurent series I'm having trouble.  I'm hoping, with the new identity below that someone can offer a little more insight.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove the first identity it is sufficient to consider that
$$ \frac{e^x-1}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1.$$
Now write both factors as Taylor series around $x=0$ and take the Cauchy product of such series.

To prove Euler's identity, consider that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{e^x-1} = -\frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^2} = \frac{1}{1-e^x}\cdot\left(-1+\frac{1}{1-e^x}\right)$$
then take the Laurent series of the LHS around $x=0$ and compare it with the product of the Laurent series for the factors in the RHS.

Comment: Thank you Jack.  I haven't worked with Laurent series before and was wondering how you do that?  I've looked up Laurent series on Wikipedia, but Laurent series deal in the complex realm.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: I used Laurent series just for simplicity. You can deduce the Euler's identity also by differentiating $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$, that is a real analytic function in a neighbourhood of zero.

Comment: I'm really not seeing how to get the identity.  I've differentiated the function giving me $$\frac{1}{e^x-1}[1-x-b(x)]$$  If I take $b'(x)$ of the power series representation, I get $$b'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{kx^{k-1}B_k}{k!}}$$.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven, I meant  : $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{x e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}.$$ Take the square as a product of two series and rearrange.

Comment: I'm sorry, Jack, I'm really struggling understanding.  Take the square of what?  the derivative above?  I'm trying to use the identity I added in the edit to show that $-(n+1)B_n$ is some finite convolution series, right?  So somehow if I can set two series equal I can compare their similar terms.  But I'm scribbling and I'm just not seeing how to do it.

Comment: Ok, step-by-step. What are the coefficients of the Taylor series of $\frac{x^2}{(e^x-1)^2}$ around zero?

Comment: Well if I look at $b(x)^2$, the coefficients are $\sum_{j=0}^k{\frac{B_jB_{k-j}}{(k-j)!}}$

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Nice. However, the derivative of $\sum a_n x^n $ is $\sum n a_n x^{n-1}$. Can you see now what happens when differentiating $b(x)$?

Comment: Somewhat...see this post for some of my work on trying to condense this problem.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950003/simplify-a-power-series

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: I have just seen it and replied.

Comment: This is definitely helping.  This is now what I have:  $$\sum_{j=0}^k{\binom{k}{j}\frac{B_jB_{k-j}}{k!}}=\frac{(1-k)B_k}{k!}-\frac{kB_{k-1}}{k!}$$

Comment: Now I can just write as $$\sum_{j=o}^k{\binom{k}{j}B_jB_{k-j}}=(1-k)B_k-kB_{k-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

So I have $$\sum_{j=0}^{k}{\binom{k}{j}B_jB_{k-j}}=(1-k)B_k-kB_{k-1}$$
But
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}{\binom{k}{j}B_jB_{k-j}}=2B_0B_k+2B_1B_{k-1}+\sum_{j=2}^{k-2}B_jB_{k-j}$$
Since $B_0=1, B_1=-1/2, \binom{k}{0}=1, \binom{k}{1}=k$,
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}{\binom{k}{j}B_jB_{k-j}}=2B_k-kB_{k-1}+\sum_{j=2}^{k-2}B_jB_{k-j}=B_k-kB_k-kB_{k-1}$$
Therefore, the unneeded $B_{k-1}$ term disappears and I'm left with 
$$\sum_{j=2}^{k-2}\binom{k}{j}B_jB_{k-j}=-B_k-kB_k=-(k+1)B_k$$