# Simplify a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I am studying bernouli numbers and I'm having trouble condensing a power series.
In particular, I'm studying the equation
$$b(x)^2=(1-x)b(x)-xb'(x)$$
where
$$b(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{B_k}{k!}x^k}=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$$
If I use the power series expansion and plug into the above equation, I get
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{B_jB_{k-j}}{j!(k-j)}\right)}x^k=(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{B_k}{k!}x^k}-x\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{kB_k}{k!}x^{k-1}}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{B_k}{k!}x^k}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{B_k}{k!}x^{k+1}}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{kB_k}{k!}x^k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{(1-k)B_k}{k!}x^k}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{B_k}{k!}x^{k+1
}}$$
My trouble comes here.  I want to condense this side in terms of a single $B_k$ but all attempts are falling short.  I can write the power series but generally i have both the $B_k$ and the $B_{k+1}$th term.

EDIT:
Let me add some of my work.

I can now get both in similar forms:
$$1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{B_jB_{k-j}}{j!(k-j)}\right)}x^k=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\left(\frac{(1-k)B_k}{k!}-\frac{B_{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right)}x^k$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what do you know about Bernoulli numbers with an odd index?

Hint$^2$: $\frac{x}{e^x-1}+\frac{x}{2}$ is an even function, hence $B_{2k+1}=0$ for any $k>0$;

Hint$^3$: in the RHS of the last line of your question, just one term survives.

Comment: Okay, so $$\sum_{j=0}^k{\frac{B_jB_{k-j}}{j!(k-j)!}}=\left(\frac{(1-k)B_k}{k!}-\frac{B_{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right)$$ Depending on the $k$, one of the RHS cancels and as you know, the one I'm most interested in is the Left term on the RHS.  Therefore, I need $k$ to be even so $k-1$ is odd.  $k$ also has to be greater than 0 since I can't have $(0-1)!$ on the RHS.